# Joi validation on payload where value name has a hyphen

Tags: node.js, joi, hapi

As it says in the title i cant get the joi validation to work on a value in my payload with a hypen in its name. The value is called 'search-type'. My validation looks like this

```
  options: {
    validate: {
      payload: joi.object({
        value1: joi.string().required(),
        value2: joi.string().required(),
        search-type: joi.string().required()
      }),
      failAction: (request, h, err) => {
        return h.redirect('/search').takeover()
      }
    }
  }
```

Ive tried putting the name in square brackets like this

```
 options: {
   validate: {
     payload: joi.object({
       value1: joi.string().required(),
       value2: joi.string().required(),
       searchType:['search-type'] joi.string().required()
     }),
     failAction: (request, h, err) => {
       return h.redirect('/search').takeover()
     }
   }
 }
```

but the 'joi.' after it flags up in linting and says 'joi.' is an unexpected token?

Comment: try searchType: .["search-type"]

Comment: thanks but still says says 'joi.' is an unexpected token after the square brackets

Comment: just use "search-type" instead of search-type. I tested it at https://hapi.dev/family/joi/tester/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 options: {
   validate: {
     payload: joi.object({
       value1: joi.string().required(),
       value2: joi.string().required(),
       'search-type': joi.string().required()
     }),
     failAction: (request, h, err) => {
       return h.redirect('/search').takeover()
     }
   }
 }
```

Since this is Joi I am guessing you don't need to access that property anywhere else, but you would do that with `options.validate['search-type']` and not `options.validate.search-type` as the `-` would be interpreted as the subtraction operator.